# Restore deleted file from Android source code

Tags: android, build, repository

I'm building Android source and deleted some `.java` files from the framework. I made a repo sync hoping that this restore the deleted file but it didn't happen.

How can I restore this and other deleted files from original source tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check damages:

```
$ repo status
project device/samsung/maguro/                  (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 -m     full_maguro.mk
project frameworks/base/                        (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 --     media/java/android/media/#AudioSystem.java#
 -d     media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java
project frameworks/opt/telephony/               (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 -d     src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java
project packages/apps/Phone/                    (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 -d     src/com/android/phone/InCallScreen.java
 -d     src/com/android/phone/PhoneUtils.java
```

restore files:

```
$ repo forall -c 'git reset --hard ; git clean -fdx'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you can right-click on the project or folder and select "Restore From Local History".

If the files are already purged from your local history for some reason then it will depend on which source control system you are using and whether you committed your changes.